# Add opacity to one of the many background images

Tags: css, background-image

I have this CSS style:

```
.Right-Side-BG {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(./white.svg), linear-gradient(to bottom, #598bd7, 
    #165594);
}
```

I need svg image to have 0.21 opacity, how do I do that?

Comment: Just simply user opacity:0.2 or whatever you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need another way to solve it. You can make the whole element (e.g. the div containing the image) transparent using for example:

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

If you can make sure that your other content is not in this div but in other elements this will work. There is no "opacity"-effect that only applies to background images.

Comment: Thanks. I simply added opacity to the image itself.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is about to add opacity to only background, not containing elements. Then you can use pseudo element `:after` add background image in it. Now you can set `opacity` to it and must set `z-index: -1` making it as background image. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.myDiv:after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('https://www.bmw.com/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/4-series/gran-coupe/2017/images-and-videos/images/BMW-4-series-gran-coupe-images-and-videos-1920x1200-10.jpg.asset.1487328157424.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

> So here you could see only the background image have opacity(transparency) not `.child` with in it(a red box).